# C++ file IO seeking to a specific line

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

for instance, I have this **test.txt** containing :

```
apple
computer
glass
mouse
blue
ground
```

then, I want to retrieve one random line from the text file.
here's my code :

```
ifstream file;
file.open("test.txt", ios::in);
char word[21];

int line = rand()%6 + 1;
for (int x = 0 ; x < line ; x++)
   test.getline (word, 21);

cout << word;
```

the problem is the variable 'word' always contains the first line, no matter what random number given...

Comment: Are you seeding the generator (by calling `srand`) somewhere prior to this code?

Comment: Btw, we know that you need help, you don't have to state it explicitly, and please don't say "THX" before there is anything to thank for ;)

Comment: oh I forgot about calling srand... I'll update now , THX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seed the random number as suggested by the comments above

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
//...other includes and code

ifstream file;
file.open("abc.txt", ios::in);
char word[21];
srand( time(NULL) );
int line = rand()%6 + 1;

for (int x = 0 ; x < line ; x++)
   file.getline (word, 21);

cout << word;
```

Comment: if you'er using seekg, it will only get how many bytes in the first line, whlist every line has a different number of bytes. So, it's not specifically get 1 line.... I've tried ur code, and it returned only a part of the string in a line...

Comment: i know i did notice that , that is why i posted the second snippet. which should work as expected.

Comment: is getline(char*, int) moves the pointer to the next line ?? THX for the solution anyway hehe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this process for large number of lines, here is more efficient way:

- Create an array which can hold strings.
- Put each word in array such that array index=line no.
- Now generate random number and access it with array index.